# What should be tested (TDD) in simple entities?

Tags: php, symfony, unit-testing, testing, tdd

I am learning code testing (TDD) and wondering what should be tested for simple entities in Symfony?

From official documentation:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="category")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CategoryRepository")
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="category")
     */
    private $products;
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->products = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Add product
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Product $product
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function addProduct(\AppBundle\Entity\Product $product)
    {
        $this->products[] = $product;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove product
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Product $product
     */
    public function removeProduct(\AppBundle\Entity\Product $product)
    {
        $this->products->removeElement($product);
    }

    /**
     * Get products
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getProducts()
    {
        return $this->products;
    }
}
```

Second:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", scale=2)
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set price
     *
     * @param string $price
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get price
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set category
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Category $category
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setCategory(\AppBundle\Entity\Category $category = null)
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get category
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Category
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }
}
```

I thought I had to create an Entity folder and within CategoryTest file:

```
namespace Tests\AppBundle\Entity;

use AppBundle\Entity\Tag;
use AppBundle\Form\DataTransformer\TagArrayToStringTransformer;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class CategoryTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    public function testGetName()
    {
        $category = new \AppBundle\Entity\Category();
        $category->setName('test');
        $this->assertSame('test', $category->getName());
    }
}
```

So... In TDD I should testing all fields? For Product entity I should testing name, price and description?

If yes, how to deal with refactoring? In these cases I must use in all methods "$product = new Product();";

For a name field I might need to do another test? What?

Should I also test relationships or do it in functional tests?

Comment: If you code first and then write the tests, it isn't TDD... BTW, TDD ensures that you have a test for everything you wrote, so you should create a test for everything you want to write.

Comment: @GabrielHeming I know, but I'm just learning, so I'm asking how this should look for an entity. I wanted to give an example of how the entity looks in Symfony, because not everyone knows this framework. The documentation has nothing to do with TDD, so I gave the tags "testing and unit-testing" so that developers of other languages would tell me how to use TDD for entities.

Comment: Take a look in TDD Coding Dojo. There's examples/exercises for any kind of language that has Unit Test.

Comment: TDD is also considered a design choice. By writing tests first, this helps shape the design. Make a list of all the things your application needs to do (i.e.. requirements), then write a test for each one. Start by picking a simple test to get going and keep it simple, letting the tests guide the design. You can also refactor later (and should as part of the TDD cycle)

Comment: Is this a Symfony application that you are testing and supporting? If so, some of the comments may not be applicable (as you can use `php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities` to generate setters and getters). I also have a question, If it's a Symfony application that you are developing, testing and supporting: what do you want to "achieve" overall?

Answer (score 1):

It is a good practice to `Entities` have no (complex) logic inside. In fact it should be just representing your model. And since there is no logic, there is not much to test actually. When you check [Symfony Demo app](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-demo) you will find no tests for entities and I believe it is done this way intentionally.

In case your application is not the only one using database I would consider writing functional tests for entities which will ensure you that someone else did not change database structure (for example by dropping column in table) without letting you know. One of possible ways to achieve that is running a simple query on table (entity) you are testing:

```
public function checkEntityDefinition($entityName)
{         $this->em->getRepository($entityName)
            ->createQueryBuilder('t')
            ->setMaxResults(1)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getArrayResult();
}
```

There are no assertion here but this will throw an exception when Entity definition does not match database

Comment: Anemic models are certainly a common practice, but not necessarily a good one. https://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html

Comment: I understand the theory behind that but I'm afraid it's hard to implement in Symfony & Doctrine ecosystem. Doctrine does not ever call Entity's constructor ( http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/architecture.html#entities ) hence doing proper dependency injection is hard and I can't imagine any complex logic without dependencies. Can you point out any big / popular Symfony's projects implementing this theory?

Comment: @Gerry, _anemic models not a good one_ only from Object-Oriented programming point of view.

Comment: @TomaszMadeyski That Doctrine does not call the constructor  (nor setters) actually facilitates this approach, it certainly does not make an argument for anemic models. The goal is not to inject services and use them inside the entities, but to encapsulate logic with the data it is working on. An example would be `$invoice->calculateVat()`.

Comment: @TomaszMadeyski And I'm afraid I can point to just as many big / popular Symfony projects that apply this than to ones that don't :) Projects tend to be closed-source. Plenty of resources about it though.